# Get GLSL linker error description on Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glsl

It seems that `glGetProgramInfoLog` (and a matching function pointer type `PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGARBPROC`) are undefined in Windows' OpenGL header and the function also seems to be missing from the DLL – I didn't find the string "wglGetProgram" in opengl32.dll.

Is there another way to get the same functionality on Windows?

`glGetInfoLogARB` seems to be an alternative but always returns empty strings on mobile platforms, so i guess there's a difference to `glGetProgramInfoLog`?!

Comment: have you initialized OpenGL 2.* (or higher) properly> using some extension loading library like Glew/Glee... or manually?

Comment: @fen: Please don't suggest the use of defunct libraries like GLee.

Answer (score 2):

I'd double check the graphics drivers are up to date. Then check nothing's messed with your GL headers and double check the include paths of your compiler.

I think GLEW comes with a tool to list everything your current GL version has.

There's a program called "depends" that will tell you what DLLs are being loaded by your executable. This might be useful to double check there isn't another DLL being found and used instead.

Comment: Right, GLEW has a definition for GL 2.x and newer. Since my header is for GL 1.1, I decided for a simple solution - see my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If your GL header is 1.1, you probably don't have recent graphics drivers installed (or maybe the card simply doesn't support recent GL?). I'd try installing the latest version either way.

Comment: The header comes from the Windows SDK and has nothing to do with the driver afaik.

Comment: @AndiDog aak ok, that might be your answer then - assuming you haven't, get the latest glew, include glew.h before gl.h and call glewInit() before making any recent GL calls.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL DLL that ships with Windows only implements OpenGL 1.1. The only functions you can call without driver intervention on Windows are from OpenGL 1.1.

In order to call anything newer, you need to use `wglGetProcAddress (...)` which will communicate with the ICD (Installable Client Driver) to get the entry-point for OpenGL extension functions.

If you use something like GLEW, this can all be handled for you. Be aware that none of these symbols are completely resolved at link-time. When you use GLEW, you effectively have a bunch of NULL pointers that are replaced with the entry-point addresses for each function when you initialize the library. So, just because the compiler/linker does not complain that a function does not exist when using GLEW, does not mean you will actually be able to use that function at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

The header version I'm using ("Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl\GL.h") doesn't include that function because only the GL_VERSION_1_1 macro is defined. I decided not to screw around with the header and just use the function `glGetInfoLogARB` instead which behaves the same way on desktop platforms and has a fully compatible signature. On ES 2.0 platforms, I'm using `glGetProgramInfoLog` directly because `glGetInfoLogARB` only gives me an empty string in case of shader linker errors.

Comment: Um, what does this mean? There is no "glGetInfoLog" function, and there certainly is no "glGetinfoLog" function.

Comment: There is "glGetInfoLogARB" (sorry, forgot the suffix) which you can get with `wglGetProcAddress("glGetInfoLogARB")`. It's all a bit confusing because there doesn't seem to be official documentation for the function, but it exists and works, so it's okay for the moment.

Comment: This is because the ARB extension for `GL_ARB_shader_objects` pre-dates OpenGL 2.0. When the spec for OpenGL 2.0 was finalized, they based GLSL off the ARB extension but changed a LOT of function names (more than simply lopping off the ARB suffix). If you are using GLSL on a system that is pre-OpenGL 2.0 then you would use the ARB functions, otherwise use the OpenGL 2.0 GLSL functions (e.g. `glGetInfoLogARB (...)` becomes `glGetProgramInfoLog (...)` and `glUseProgramObjectARB (...)` becomes `glUseProgram (...)`).

Comment: I figured this goes without saying, but after reading your comment again... do not mix and match GLSL functions. If you use the ARB variant anywhere in your software at run-time, you must always use the ARB functions. Using `glGetInfoLogARB (...)` on a program linked with `glLinkProgram (...)` should return an empty string for obvious reasons.